# Need finite 'xlim' values for R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and tryign to replicate the barplot Shiny example from the tutorial ([Link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html). However, I am getting an error. Is this because of the type of dataframe? I read several other 'xlim' error pages, and didn't seem to get anywhere since they were mostly for non-barplot examples. I have replicated the dataframe in the same structure as the example, which was where I wanted to begin. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Warning in min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
```

df:

```
             Name           
Facility    Atlanta Chicago Boston  New York
Home        5   0   12  5
Post Acute  23  5   43  0
Relative    7   72  33  0
Hospital    18  34  19  67
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

## Define where the data file exists
setwd("C:/Users/R")

## Name the object to hold csv
dta <- read.csv(file = "data.csv", na.strings =c("", "NA"))

## Assign new object as data frame and get column info
call <- data.frame(dta)

df <- table(call$Facility, call$name)

shinyServer(function(input, output){
#   # Create the data frame to display     

    output$dcPlot <- renderPlot({

      # Render a barplot
      barplot(df[,input$name],
              main=input$name,
              ylab="Number of Discharges",
              xlab="Discharge Type")
    })
 })
```

Here is the ui.R

```
# Bring in the library
library(shiny)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Discharge by Provider"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "Name",
                    label = "Name:",
                    choices=colnames(df)),
        hr(),
        ## This input goes below the drop down bars 
        helpText("Data from Episode Connect monthly Call Forms")
      ),

      # Create a spot for the barplot
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("dcPlot")  
      )

    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the output of the `table` function is not a dataframe but a `table`.

Try:

```
df <- as.data.frame(unclass(table(call$Facility, call$name)))
```

Also, in your `server.R` you have a typo when you get the `input` data, the `inputId` is `Name` in your `ui.R`

Comment: Ah man, can't even tell you how much that made my day. Thank you. The next thing I am trying to figure out is the barplot labels along the x-axis.